# jQuery code doesn't work in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do following with jQuery:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script> 
        $('#test').hover(function(){
            alert('sub');
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that HTML DOM element with `id="test"` exists.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#test').hover(function() {
                alert('sub');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

By the way, CodeIgniter has nothing to do with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are accessing an element which does not exists.

Try this:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#test').hover(function() {
                alert('sub');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```